# Facebook Developer - Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 26: failed creating formpost data

Tags: php, facebook, image, facebook-php-sdk

I read a lot on this platform, but no one seems to get the answer about my problem.

There is my code:

```
$file= $str.".png";

$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);

$post_data = array(
  "message" => "my message."
); 
$post_data[basename($file)] = '@' . dirname(__FILE__) . '/'.$file.'';
$data = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'post', $post_data);
```

I got a CurlException: 26 error.
I even try with this one :

```
$post_data[basename($file)] = '@' . realpath($file);
```

But I got the same error.

I first consider my problem was on $file.
If I do an echo on this one, I a have the image name like this : 0gwP7eDAtb2X.png

Now, if I test this code:

```
$post_data[basename($file)] = '@' . realpath(0gwP7eDAtb2X.png);
```

The picture is correctly uploaded on my wall.